# Android in some cases String.format returns strange results

Tags: java, android, string, formatting

I discovered that in some unknown cases the method:

```
int number = 510;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(String.format("%05d", number));
System.out.println(sb);
//I expect "00510" but it prints "?????" (not a random number but precisely 5 question marks)
```

Maybe it's related to the Locale, I cannot replicate.
Someone can explain in which cases this happens?

**EDIT:**

I tried to change all available Locale but on my device the result is always correct.
Maybe it's related to the StringBuilder appender?

Comment: whats the output you got from `string.format`? what was the `number` generated ?

Comment: The output are 5 question marks.

Comment: You should debug it and make sure the issue is what you think, this could be a font issue

Comment: I got this error from the log of my users, if I cannot reproduce this error on my device I can't resolve.

Comment: I suppose you always use "number" as int, right? It could be null sometimes if you declare it Integer, and this could be the problem. Be aware of it.

Comment: Hello, have you solved this issue? I have the same problem and can not figure out why. Please update question if you found a solution. Thanks.